# Is this kind of definition of vector space rigorous?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I use Prof. Sergei Treil's $\textit{Linear Algebra Done Wrong}$ as my first book in self learning linear algebra, and I have finished the whole book. I really think that it is an excellent book, however, I really can't agree with the definition of vector space in this book. In fact, I think it is not rigorous.
[image]

When he consider the scalar multiplication, he doesn't tell people what field these scalars in, and just look at point 5,Multiplicative identity, he states that 1$\vec{v}$=$\vec{v}$,however, he doesn't explain what is 1? what field is this 1 in?

I am not an american students, so I don't know if there's some convention when referring to scalars. Hope that someone can help me with it.

Comment: If you read the entire right hand page, it explains why the author did not mention fields in the defintion of a vector space.

Comment: @Ted I know that right hand page mentions field, however, I think that this kind of order is a little uncomfortable. Furthermore, he mentions field after he said 0=0v, -v=(-1)v. In fact, without field, the 0 and -1 are meaningless. So, I think in describing vector spaces, his order of mentioning field in the last is not rigorous.